# google.maps.LatLngBounds () issue

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to find if a latitude and longitude exists in a rectangle or not. I used following code but its having some issue i donno what.

```
    function test(boxes) {
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds (box[i]); 
        if (bounds.contains(new google.maps.LatLng(22.7287, 75.8654))) {
            alert("i am here");
        // marker is within bounds
        }
        else {
            alert("out of box");
        }
        }
}
```

if i pass constructor value as 0.0,0.0, it works while if i use boxes[i] its not executing while boxes[i] having the boundaries e.g (17.788,72.828),(21.2620,73.4602)

Comment: What is box[i]?  I suspect it is not the correct arguments for the [LatLngBounds constructor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) (two google.maps.LatLng objects).

Comment: What is the content of box[i]? See the documentation for the LatLngBounds object. The constructor takes two LatLng objects as parameters, not a "box": https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds

Comment: @geocodezip ,@Marcelo Below is the function i am using to call test function, generating the context of box.

    directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
          
          // Box around the overview path of the first route
          var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
          var boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, distance);
          //drawBoxes(boxes);
    test(boxes);
        } else {
          alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
        }
      });

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read if you would update your question with that information.  It looks like you are using the routeBoxer, in that case, the returned "boxes" would be google.maps.LatLng objects already, no need for the new google.maps.LatLng(box[i]) at all, just do (box[i].contains(new google.maps.LatLng(22.7287, 75.8654)))

Comment: Please reply this problem or if you have any suitable example with coding for POI search along route, you can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments (you really should update the question), this should work:

```
function test(boxes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    if (boxes[i].contains(new google.maps.LatLng(22.7287, 75.8654))) {
        alert("i am here");
    // marker is within bounds
    }
    else {
        alert("out of box");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if i am having multiple latitude and longitude in my mysql database then how should i check or loop through mysql lat/long falling in the route or not.